How To Easily Convert A JavaScript Array Into A Postgres BigInt Array
Simple question, but I can't seem to find a simple answer.
Step 1: I pass this into the postgresql function as json:
{
  "name" : "John Doe",
  "convert" : [32197,4234523,4235423]
}

Step 2: I would LIKE to store the id array within the database ids bigint[] column as {32197,4234523,4235423}
How could I accomplish this?

I cannot reproduce, your query works fine.

Did you just forget to commit the transaction (or forgot to enable autocommit)? Please show us your whole query as a [mcve]

Try using the function json_to_record.
Example of usage from the documentation:
create type myrowtype as (a int, b text);
select * from json_to_record('{"a":1,"b":[1,2,3],"c":[1,2,3],"e":"bar","r": {"a": 123, "b": "a b c"}}') as x(a int, b text, c int[], d text, r myrowtype)

 a |    b    |    c    | d |       r
---+---------+---------+---+---------------
 1 | [1,2,3] | {1,2,3} |   | (123,"a b c")

In your case:
SELECT * FROM json_to_record('{"name" : "John Doe", "convert" : [32197,4234523,4235423]}') as x(convert bigint[])

convert         
-------------------------
{32197,4234523,4235423}


This doesn't explain why the OP's approach isn't working

Hello @Bergi I tried to answer the question posed in the title. To understand why Ethan's example doesn't work, we need to see a more complete code listing.

The easiest way I found to do this was:
    SET 
      ids = ARRAY(SELECT json_array_elements_text(d->'convert')::BIGINT)

Where I am pulling the elements of the array out individually as text objects, then recasting to BIGINT's before pushing them back into an ARRAY
